# Get mac address based on ip in filter wireshark

Tags: dhcp, wireshark, mac-address, filter

i am a test engineer writing some test cases.
I am trying to write a test which has to be performed in wireshark.
However, my collegues aren't that "into wireshark" and i would like to keep it as simple as possible for them.

The core of the TC is that they have to check something in the DHCP protocol based on the mac address.

Is there a way in wireshark to get the mac address in a filter based on a filter of the ip?
basically a subquery inside a query.

something like this.

Filter: bootp and eth.address==((ip.addr==192.168.0.1).macaddress)
I don't want them to start looking for the mac first, since there are multiple devices connected.
There is also no easy access to the mac on the test device itself.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, as soon as i pressed the post button, the answer came to me..

bootp and bootp.ip.your==169.254.1.11
i basically don't need the mac-address to see the related dhcp ack response